# Image Overlay Issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, overlay

I am using the following code for image overlay effect. I get from some website, just now  I noticed that its not working on firefox and IE it showing only black background. But when we hover it's shows picture here is my code. I am using bootstrap with it.

```css
   .hovereffect {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: default;
  background:#000;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.hovereffect .overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 50px 20px;
}

.hovereffect img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  max-width: none;
  width: calc(100% + 20px);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-10px,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(-10px,0,0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.hovereffect:hover img {
  opacity: 0.4;
  filter: alpha(opacity=40);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

.hovereffect h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight:bold;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0.5em 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 }

.hovereffect h2:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #fff;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: transform 0.35s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(-100%,0,0);
}

.hovereffect:hover h2:after {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

.hovereffect a, .hovereffect p {
  color: #FFF;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
}
.hovereffect a:hover
{
 color:#fff;
 text-decoration:none;
}
.hovereffect:hover a, .hovereffect:hover p {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="hovereffect">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x250" alt="">
            <div class="overlay">
                <h2>Effect 12</h2>
    <p> 
     <a href="#">LINK HERE</a>
    </p> 
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Everywhere added ```-webkit-``` in your styling also add same for ```-moz-```.

Comment: @aavrug not working bro.

Comment: For me it is working fine even without adding the ```-moz-``` part.

Comment: can you show the output image ? as it works in my mozilla using this code : https://jsfiddle.net/gtofv371/

Comment: @BhavinShah please check this link: http://bkg-website.tk/new/divisions.php

Answer (score 0):

```css
.hovereffect {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: default;
  background:#000;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.hovereffect img{
  opacity:0;
}

.hovereffect .overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 50px 20px;
}

.hovereffect img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  max-width: none;
  width: calc(100% + 20px);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-10px,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(-10px,0,0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.hovereffect:hover img {
  opacity: 0.4;
  filter: alpha(opacity=40);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

.hovereffect h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight:bold;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0.5em 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 }

.hovereffect h2:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #fff;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: transform 0.35s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(-100%,0,0);
}

.hovereffect:hover h2:after {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

.hovereffect a, .hovereffect p {
  color: #FFF;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
}
.hovereffect a:hover
{
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.hovereffect:hover a, .hovereffect:hover p {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row">


<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="hovereffect">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://isomerica.net/~mlah/art/photos/small.nature.puffball.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="overlay">
                <h2>Effect 12</h2>
                <p> 
                    <a href="#">LINK HERE</a>
                </p> 
            </div>
    </div>
</div>



</div>
```

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gtofv371/1/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: it is working in my chrome. which version are you using in chrome?

Comment: I have 54.0 chrome version in my ubuntu

Comment: I am using 55.0 in windows.

Comment: it's working in windows in chrome  55.0 . i just have checked in one of my colleagues' desktop.